# Favicon not updating; flashes new version, then reverts

Tags: html, web, favicon

I'm trying to update the favicon on my site, but something strange is happening: it shows the new version for a split-second, then reverts to the old icon. Check out [yesinsights.com](https://www.yesinsights.com) to see what I mean -- watch the favicon carefully. [Here's what the favicon should look like.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/yesinsights.com/assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=3)

I've tried adding a query parameter to the favicon url, I've tried clearing my browser's cache (I'm using Firefox on Ubuntu), I've tried all kinds of variations on the `<link>` tag, and nothing seems to work. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe a script changes the favicon?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, but thanks.

Comment: Your icon looks different in different resolutions: [i.imgur.com/kLWJsai.png](http://i.imgur.com/kLWJsai.png). The browser fetches the 16×16 one with the white background, whereas your link shows the 64×64 one with the blue background.

Comment: Wow, that's new to me. How does the favicon.ico format store different resolutions, and how do I edit them? I opened the image in Gimp, but all I saw was the 64x64 version.

Comment: It is simply a Windows icon. Should be pretty easy to google for the spec. I'm using IcoFx as the editor.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! This has been bugging me for a while now.

Comment: Hey @UweKeim, I created a new favicon using an ico editor, and it worked! Thanks again! If you post your comments as an answer, I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Great! It is 1:20 am here, and I'm already in bed, will post tomorrow. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(As of request, here is [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603882/favicon-not-updating-flashes-new-version-then-reverts?noredirect=1#comment66517690_39603882) as an answer)*

Your icon looks different in different pixel dimensions:

[image]

The browser fetches the 16×16 one with the white background, whereas [your link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/yesinsights.com/assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=3) shows the 64×64 one with the blue background.

[See this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) for details about the ICO file format.

**Solution 1**

One solution could be to fetch a tool to edit your icon to only include the 16×16 image and delete all other images inside the icon file.

Personally, I've used [Microangelo](http://microangelo.us/) and [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) as an icon editor (both commercial).

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, you could generate a favicon by uploading a PNG image to one of the various online tools like e.g. [this one](http://www.favicon-generator.org/).

**Solution 3**

Another solution is to not use an ICO file at all but a PNG file by using something like this inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://my-domain.com/my-favicon.png" />
```

As mentioned by Ajpocus in the comment below, this works for most browsers but in the IE land [only for IE 11+](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-png).

Comment: I was going to use a PNG favicon, but they aren't supported in IE 9-10. Only IE 11 and Edge. http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-png

Comment: No problem @UweKeim. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm usually I close and reopen my browser and the cache favicon is refreshed.

Comment: Like Wim's answer said, it's probably because you don't have the old favicon cached. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use versioning to force the browser to display the new icon like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/favicon.ico?v=RyyR6aw6zk" />
```

FYI, the icon shows correctly for me but that's because it's not cached for me. Favicons are hard to remove from cache.

I see your referencing the icon from Amazon. Check if your icon isn't also located in the root of your site.

Comment: Yeah, versioning is what I meant when I said I added a query parameter to the url. Good to know you're seeing the updated favicon though, thanks. And I do have a copy of the favicon in the root of my site, and it's the updated version as well.

Comment: I think the favicon in the root gets loaded first and cached. Maybe just change the fav url to href="/favicon.ico?v=3